# How to disable time zone redirection over RDP for Azure Virtual Desktop on client, not server

Tags: azure, remote-desktop, rdp, vdi

I was assigned an Azure Virtual Desktop. The time zone on my laptop and time zone of AVD differ. When I connect to AVD, the time zone in the RDP session is set to the time zone of my laptop. The AVD is managed via Windows domain and I do not have administrative privileges on it. Is there some kind of client side setting to not initiate the time zone change in the new RDP session?

Comment: There is not a client-managed setting for the native RDP client. This would require a customized client/wrapper. Most people either want it, or disable it host-wide.  Probably worth noting that for administrative purposes, which is what this forum is entirely about, most people I know set cloud-based resources to UTC. There should be a support option made available to you, provided to you by your support team, for an exception process to provide this capability *on the Azure Virtual Desktop*, which is the only management option available.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem with a little bit of cmd scripting

avd.cmd:

```
@echo off
set AVDTZ=Central Standard Time
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`tzutil /g`) DO (set LOCALTZ=%%F)
tzutil /s "%AVDTZ%"
start "" "C:\Program Files\Remote Desktop\msrdcw.exe"
pause
tzutil /s "%LOCALTZ%"
```

Save the timezone in LOCALTZ variable, set local timezone to the desired one, launch AVD RDP client. Then you need to connect manually and hit any button at the prompt of the pause command. Then the timezone will be reverted back to your original one on the local computer.